# Make more than one database call in wordpress plugin (PHP CRUD)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have 2 pieces of code from a simple plugin that work independently from each other but don't work together.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    if(has_presence($_POST['product_name'])){

        insert_row_into_table('CAL_products');
        show_errors();
        if(has_presence($wpdb->last_query)) {
            echo "Update Successful";
        } else {
            echo "Update Failed";
        }
    } else {
        echo "The field 'Product Name' cannot be blank.";
    }
}
```

And this one

```
$results_array = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wpCMS_CAL_products ORDER BY id ASC");

echo build_table_from_results_array($results_array);
```

The functions are included at the bottom.

The problem I have is that when the page loads there is no $_POST so it skips over the if statement and builds the table. This table builds fine.

When the form is submitted the if statements come back true and the new value is added to the database successfully, but then the table doesn't build until the page is refreshed. If the code to build the table is put at the top above the if statement it builds fine but doesn't include the new value until the page is refreshed. 

**Is it possible to add a new item to the database table before the results are populated to the HTML table?**

```
function insert_row_into_table($table_name){
global $wpdb;

$prefix =  $wpdb->prefix;   //Define the wordpress table prefix
$table = $prefix . $table_name; //Build the table name
unset($_POST['submit']);
echo print_r($_POST);
$data = $_POST; //collect the data from post

$wpdb->insert( $table, $data ); //insert data into the table  
}

function show_errors(){                                   
    echo $wpdb->show_errors();
    echo $wpdb->print_error();
}

function has_presence($value) {
    return isset($value) && $value !== "";
}

function build_table_from_results_array($results_array) {

$out  = "";
$out .= "<table class=\"widefat\">";

$out .= "<thead>";
foreach($results_array[0] as $key => $element) {
    if($key == "id") {
        $out .= "<th class=\"id-column\">";
        $out .= strtoupper($key);
        $out .= "</th>";
    } else {
        $out .= "<th>";
        $out .= ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $key));
        $out .= "</th>";
    }
}
$out .= "</thead>";
$out .= "<tbody>";

$i = 0;
foreach($results_array as $key => $element){

    if($i % 2 === 0) $extraclass= "alternate";
    $out .= "<tr class=\"$extraclass\">";
    $i++;
    $extraclass="";

    foreach($element as $subkey => $subelement){
        $out .= "<td>$subelement</td>";
    }

    $out .= "<td><a href=\"#\">EDIT</a></td>";
    $out .= "</tr>";
}

$out .= "</tbody>";
$out .= "</table>";

return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general pattern for this type of page is [Post-Redirect-Get.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)  You could, for instance, pull the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) block out into a separate file called processForm.php. The form's action parameter is changed to processForm.php. The form sends $_POST data to processForm which inserts the new database records, and processForm in turn redirects the user back to the original page which gets the results.

If you want a one-page solution using the above code, add this code at the very top of the file, before you output anything at all. This starts the output buffer, which is usually necessary if you want to use the header() command to redirect.

```
ob_start();
```

Then edit the if(isset) block:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(has_presence($_POST['product_name'])){

        insert_row_into_table('CAL_products');
        show_errors();
        if(has_presence($wpdb->last_query)) {
            echo "Update Successful";
            header("Location: index.php"); //change index.php to the current page
            //header("Location: ".$from); //or use a variable
        } else {
            echo "Update Failed";
        }
    } else {
        echo "The field 'Product Name' cannot be blank.";
    }

}
```

Finally, add this at the very end of the script to close the output buffer:

```
ob_end_flush();
```

Essentially, this code refreshes the page on success after the new entries are inserted into the database. This should allow your table to include the new records.

Comment: I will try this out hopefully tomorrow(changing internet providers.)once I've tried it I'll let you know and mark it. I thought about this but the WordPress plugin setup means that the first line of code is executed far down the DOM the admin menus load first, so I might have to make a two page solutuon . I'll let you know thanks for this. I didn't know about ob_start.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update. If you're using the two page solution, you'll only need the ob functions on the processing page, so it can redirect back to the original page once the records are inserted.

Comment: OK so here is the situation. Wordpress seems to make this impossible. In the plugin the wordpress admin stops ob_start() being at the file, so this does work, if i break out of the structure (i tried tricking wordpress) by sending to ../../../../wp-content/...... and choosing the file path of a file inside my plugin I get there and it redirects me back... so long as there is no database call. once you break out of the structure the $wpdb variable no longer exists. Do you have any suggestions before I make a two page setup with a back button?

Comment: I've also marked this as the correct answer as from a PHP and MySQL approach your answer is correct so will provide help for others that have a non-wordpress issue. However, it doesn't help my situation. I'm thinking the best approach will be to send to a page which says product updated successfully and include a back button. Otherwise it involves very smelly code.

Comment: The problem was with this line. Thanks for the help. it now works on one page and I don't need the redirect. However, I shall remember the ob_start() hack should I need it in the future.

if(has_presence($wpdb->last_query)) {
            echo "Update Successful";
        } else {
            echo "Update Failed";
        }